# Setting :deploy_to from server config in Capistrano3

Tags: deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

In my Capistrano 3 deployment, I would like to set the `set :deploy_to, -> { "/srv/www/#{fetch(:application)}" }` so the `:deploy_to` is different for each server it deploys to.

In my `staging.rb` file I have:

```
server 'dev.myserver.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app db}, install_path: 'mycustom/path'
server 'dev.myserver2.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app db}, install_path: 'mycustom/other/path'
```

My question is: would it possible to use the "install_path" I defined, in my `:deploy_to`? If that's possible, how would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after looking around, I came onto an issue from one of the developer of Capistrano, stating specifically that it **can't be done**

Quote from the [Github issue](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/1399#issuecomment-83591547):

> Not possible, sorry. fetch() (as is documented widely) reads values
>   set by set(), the only reason to use set() and fetch() over regular
>   ruby variables is to provide a consistent API between plugins and
>   extensions, and because set() can take a Proc to be resolved later.
>
> The variables you are setting in the host object via the server()
>   command belong to an individual host, some of them, user, roles, etc
>   have special meanings. For more information see
>   https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#do-something-different-on-one-host-or-another-depending-on-a-host-property.
>
> If you specifically need to deploy to a different directory on each
>   machine you probably should not be using the built-in tasks (they
>   don't fit your needs), and rather copy the deploy.rake from the Gem
>   into your own project, and modify it as you need. Which in this case
>   might be to not take fetch(:deploy_to), but to read that from a host
>   property.
>
> You could try to do something where before doing anything that relies
>   on calling fetch(:deploy_to), you set() it using the value from
>   host.someproperty but I'm pretty sure that'll break in exciting and
>   interesting ways.